# VS Code Extension - How to set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating an extension for VS Code. In that, before connecting to database, I need to set the env variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to path to certificate file. Normally, If I am running any javascript code(myFile.js) that connects to my database, I run following command in terminal -

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='path-to-certificate-file'
node myFile.js
```

Now, my extension has code that connects to my database, but how do i set the env variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS before running the extension ?
I tried following ways but it didn't work -

1. Used process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='path-to-certificate-file' inside extension code.
2. Set this env variable in `launch.json`

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}",
            "osx": {
                "env": {"NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS":"path-to-certificate-file"}
            }
        }
```

3. I added this line in my .zshrc file
   `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='path-to-certificate-file'` .

How env variables are set for VS Code Extension? Is there any reason or am i doing anything wrong which is why it isn't working ?